# How to change screen brightness?

Tags: android, powermanager

How I can change screen brightness in Android?

I can find how to do this for application, but I want do it for all system and permanently (until user changes it in options).

I don't need to set it for custom value. Just low brightness level, Medium brightness and Maximum will be perfect.

It is possible for example with `PowerManager` or something like that \?

Using Android 2.0+.

Comment: Take a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621490/android-2-2-adjusting-screen-brightness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = <value from 0 to 1>;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: Thanks :) This is good solution, but more solid is Khoa Le answer, because there is how delete automatic bright problem.

Comment: Now i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032588/cant-apply-system-screen-brightness-programmatically-in-android If You want save brightness even app is close, use this solution.