# How to change system brightness?

Tags: android

I want change the system brightness using my application. But as soon as i come out of that app. Brightness is again resetted to default value. What shud i do in order to make permanent change to brightness setting? I have tried few ways but all off them only work till my app is not closed.

Comment: duplicate of [How to change screen brightness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487004/how-to-change-screen-brightness?rq=1)

Comment: Yes but im not able to find a proper solution..

Comment: See below. Let me know if it works. [Changing Screen Brightness](http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/changing-screen-brightness.html)

Comment: Already tried.. Its not working..

Comment: Try this too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032588/cant-apply-system-screen-brightness-programmatically-in-android

Answer (score 0):

This code is complite work for change brigtness of android deveice.

```
Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 20);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.screenBrightness =0.2f;// 100 / 100.0f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

    startActivity(new Intent(this,RefreshScreen.class));
```

Also give below permission to manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```