# Android. Change system screen brightness immediately

Tags: java, android, screen-brightness

I am making a widget that changes system screen brightness on click.
I did it like on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487004/how-to-change-screen-brightness)
Everything works well, but changings brightness takes approximately 1 second, but I want to change it immediately, like it does default android widget.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this question is similar, correct me if I'm wrong

[Changing screen brightness programmatically (as with the power widget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646865/changing-screen-brightness-programmatically-as-with-the-power-widget)

Comment: It's not similar. He cannot change brightness after closing his app, but my widget works well. I just can't change brightness immediately.