# Updating the screen brightness in android

Tags: android, brightness, screen-brightness

here's my code to change the brightness settings of my phone.

After running the app, if I go to the settings>display>brightness of my phone, I see the value changed however not 'updated'. So when I click on the dialog box's ok/cancel button, that's when it gets updated. So am I missing a call that finally after changing the values will update the screen brightness? Thanks.

The code is in C# though, I am using Xamarin and monodroid to develop my App. Thanks people!

```
Android.Provider.Settings.System.PutInt(ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.System.ScreenBrightnessMode, 0);
int brightnessInt = (int)(1.0 * 255); //To set max brightness

Android.Provider.Settings.System.PutInt(ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.System.ScreenBrightness, brightnessInt);

View v = Window.DecorView.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
v.Invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's not on auto adjust

[Android 2.2: Adjusting screen brightness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621490/android-2-2-adjusting-screen-brightness)

The last few lines solve your problem.

Also make sure android:minSdkVersion is at least v 2.3.3

Comment: The first line of code switches the phone to MANUAL mode of brightness.
I confirm it is switching to that.
I have the target API as 4.2, however, I have to target 2.3
The next in the list after 2.3 is 3.1
Is there a way to get 2.3.3 too?

Comment: if you've already set the target api is 4.2 that's fine but the android:minSdkVersion needs to be 2.3.3(which is "10") according to that source. I wrote the wrong thing and I'll edit it.

Comment: I also tried starting a dummy activity. That doesn't work either. :( Yes, the min target version is 4.2 right now.

Comment: I'll try making one myself and see if I can find a solution :C

Comment: I am trying to look into this, might help
https://bitbucket.org/gyrussolutions/yaab/src
Thanks for looking into this! :)

Comment: I opened your app up and I don't seem to be seeing the problem. what phone are you using? I'm using a samsung galaxy s3.

Comment: I am using an S2 with an android version 4.0.4

Comment: Hold on, the link that I gave, that isn't my app omg. That is just an example I am looking at. Its an opensource app.

Comment: oh I was wondering why I couldn't find the code in the question there. Sorry about that.

Comment: I noticed that in the source you posted the checks for adjusting brightness were wrapped in a synchronize statement. try seeing if that works if you haven't already

Comment: Noope, couldn't find that wrapper in C#

Comment: it seems to have a different name http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx

Comment: Got the answer: The problem is, I was doing this in a method, I only had to now call that method using
    RunOnUiThread(()=>methodName());
Thank you so much for looking into it! :)

Comment: ah thanks and sorry I couldn't figure it out exact at first. good luck on building more things with android! :D